# Facebook Login on no native Android App "you already authorized"

Tags: javascript, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Here I present the case:

I am developing an app that uses Facebook. We are using the Facebook API via js.
The user log into mobile browser (outside of app) to Facebook.
The user then comes into the app (the user already has authorized the app on Facebook some time ago).
Then the user goes to log in options, and chooses a button entitled "log whit facebook", its a simple button with a js action as follows:

```
       $('#loginFacebookbBtn').on('vclick', function () {

            FB.login(function (response) {
                if (response.authResponse) {
                    FB.api('/me', function (response) {
                        ... do something whit the response
                    });
                } else {

                }
            }, {
                scope: "email"
            });

        });
```

Then the Facebook API show a browser popup, that ask for user credentials. I put my credentials and then the browser popup go to a second page that said:

"you already authorized (APP NAME)" (Cancel) (OK)

When I press OK, this then goes to my app but I dont want that second page on popup browser...

Sorry for my English and thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's how it works - if the user isn't logged into Facebook already they need to log in - if the user was already logged into Facebook's app on the phone they wouldn't see that screen

Comment: in this case the user dont have the facebook app on the phone

Comment: Yes, so they'll need to log in if they're not already logged into Facebook in the webview which is spawned for the auth dialog - i'm guessing in most cases the webview won't share cookies with the main browser

Comment: Is there anyway to skip that "you have already authorised the app" ?